# Resize zk modal programmatically

Tags: java, javascript, iframe, zk

I have an appliction with a modal called loginModal which contains an iframe

```
<window id="loginModal" title="Login" border="normal" position="center,top" closable="true" width="500px" height="350px" >
    <iframe src="/usermenu.zul"  id="iframeLogin" scrolling="false" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</window>
```

The iframe calls a page usermenu. In certain cases the usermenu may redirect to a verification page whose contents are larger than the modal. I would like to find a way that when doing the redirect I can resize the modal to make it bigger automatically.

Please note that the getParent returns null and doesn't return the modal object to me.

I tried to send a message to the loginModal when reaching the verification page. The message is received but I cannot resize the modal through javascript.

In the verification page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.parent.postMessage('verification','*');
</script>
```

In the loginModal

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(evt) {

    if (evt.data == 'verification') {
        loginModal.height = 500;
    }
}
</script>
```

I have tried a few variations to set the height but none of them works. I know that the message is reaching the loginModal because I can send an alert.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: just one question, why Iframe is you call an zul?

Comment: @chillworld if I understood your question well - why am i calling a zul from an iframe? - it is because in the modal i want to redirect to other zul pages depending on the case (user logged in, user needs to be verified, login failed etc) and i want this all to be handled in a modal rather than closing and opening a new modal each time.

Comment: Got it, I'll search for an example without the Iframe. This should be normally no problem (have already some thoughts)

Comment: Well, I did some testing and like you said, I lose mine original page at the end. I will ask the redirection of modal window on zk forum. Now for your java script, add px after the 500. Sometimes Zk need the px and sometimes it can be done without it.

Comment: Oke, I found your solution. (I give an answer here as example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ZK does is that it loads your `loginModal` page in one desktop and your `iframeLogin` page in another desktop. The notion of a desktop is further clarified [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/Component-based_UI).

Thus, `loginModal` is not the parent browser window of `iframeLogin`. This is why [`getParent`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/AbstractComponent.html#getParent%28%29) returns `null` when you invoke it on your iframe.

As stated in [ZK Component Reference](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Component%20Reference/Essential%20Components/Iframe#Retrieving_Component_inside_Iframe), one may not access components attached to other desktops. In other words, the information exchange between `loginModal` and `iframeLogin` is disabled.

It seems that you have one of two options:

1. Do without an iframe and use [`include`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Include.html) instead.
2. Use an iframe but define an [Event Queue](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Queues) under the group scope. Make this event queue visible to both `loginModal` and `iframeLogin`, and use it to exchange information between the two desktops you have.

**EDIT 1**

Please ensure that:

1. the client-side namespace is incorporated by inserting
   `xmlns:w="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client"` into your `window`
   tag.
2. your JS code is evaluated after creating all the widgets by inserting `defer="true"` into your `script` tag.

In your second JS snippet, `this` references the `script` widget itself. Your `window` and `script` co-exist in the same [ID space](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ID_Space). In other words, your `window` and `script` are *fellows*.

Therefore, to reference your `window` from your `script`, please use **any** of the following:

```js
this.$f('loginModal').setHeight("500px");
this.$f().loginModal.setHeight("500px");
zk.Widget.$(jq('$loginModal')[0]).setHeight("500px");
```

Instead of:

```js
loginModal.height = 500;
```

**EDIT 2**

To further exemplify, the following JS `script` would double the initial height of `loginModal`:

```js
<window id="loginModal" title="Login" border="normal" width="500px" height="350px" xmlns:w="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client">
    <script defer="true">
        this.$f('loginModal').setHeight("700px");
    </script>
</window>
```

Comment: I need the iframe to redirect to other zuls and this doesn't work with the include. Is is possible to resize the loginModal from the zul page itself using javascript? I've added a description of what I tried above.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but received the error Method setDefer not found for class org.zkoss.zul.Window. When i remove the defer="true" and run it i get a javascript error this.$f is not a function. I tried with $w aswell and same error.

I think its because I'm calling function inside a javascript tag not  zscript. The window.addEventListener and receiveMessage functions don't working in zscipt.

Comment: thanks @Sari HH I made the change but i still get the error "this.$f is not a function" and no resize :(
Edit : Do i still need to define an EventQueue with this method?

Comment: Please have a look at my 2nd EdIT. widget.$f(String) is a JS method and it has a counterpart in ZK Java API.

You don't need an EventQueue if posting/receiving a message works for you.

In your original post, you say that the message is reaching the loginModal, so simply replace the body of your conditional statement.

Comment: My mistake I misread and put all 3 in (figured it was some cross browser thing). It's working now thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `iframe` as you mention in the comment of Sari awnser.
Just add a `Composer` to your modal window

```
<window id="loginModal" ...  apply="mypkg.MyComposer">
```

and "fake" the redirect logic here.

```
class MyComposer extends SelectorComposer {

@Wire
Window loginModal;

public void doAfterCompose(Component comp){
    super.doAfterCompose(comp);
    if(checkConditionForVerificationPage){
      Executions.createComponents("/verification.zul", loginModal, null);
    } else {
      Executions.createComponents("/usermenu.zul", loginModal, null);
    }
}
}
```

My experience showed me, that it is better to avoid real redirects in zk.
Not very surprising, cos zk is ajax :)
And if you want to remove the verification page and add the usermenu after verification call

```
Events.sendEvent("onVerify", loginModal, mydata);
```

in a `Composer` of the verification page after success and add to the composer above

```
@Listen("onVerify = #loginModal")
  public void handelVerification(Event e) {
  loginModal.removeChild(loginModal.query("#idOfTopComponentFromVerificationPage"));
  Executions.createComponents("/usermenu.zul", loginModal, null);
}
```

And of course you can set the height and width of the loginModal

```
loginModal.setWidth("100px");
```

Comment: And indeed this is an other solution when you can know the redirect or not.

Comment: I tried. My problem is this. the usermenu is an access to the login once the user is logged in. When calling this page if the server sees that the user isn't logged in it redirects to the login.zul page. With this method the redirect by the server doesn't work.

Comment: Of course not, that is what I explained. You should not use redirects you had to send the event, that deletes the old content and adds the new one.
Redirects arn't ajax.